# How to make .pdf open in new window with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

How can I have all links with a `.pdf` file extension open in a new window using jQuery? I need to change this:

```
<a href="domain.com/pdf/parkingmap.pdf">parking map</a>
```

In to this:

```
<a href="domain.com/pdf/parkingmap.pdf" target="_blank">parking map</a>
```

All files are in a `/pdf` folder if that helps.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To achieve this you can select any `a` element which has a `href` property ending with `.pdf`, and add a `target="_blank"` attribute to it. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href$=".pdf"]').prop('target', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `.prop('target', '_blank');` instead of `.attr('target', '_blank');` ?

Comment: @sircapsalot `prop` is used in cases where you are amending a property which is available through the POJS element object. Things like `id`, or `src` for example. http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan do I just need to add <script>
$('a[href$=".pdf"]').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('target', '_blank');
});
</script> in the header? Doesn't seem to be working and nothing was added to links when I copied and pasted your code.

Comment: You also need a document ready handler. I'll update my answer to give you the whole thing.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  I added " $(document).ready(function() {" and it seemed to work, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One way, assuming you want links *not* ending in `pdf` to open in the same page:

```
$('a').click(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.href.split('.').pop() === 'pdf') {
            window.open(this.href);
        }
        else {
            window.location = this.href;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery one-liner:

```
$('a[href$=".pdf"]').attr('target','_blank');
```

Current Javascript:

```
for (let a of document.querySelectorAll("a")) {
    if (a.href.match("\\.pdf$")) {
        a.target = "_blank";
    }
}
```

Older browsers :

```
var anchors = document.body.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    if(anchors[i].getAttribute('href').match('\\.pdf$') {
        anchors[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    }
}
```

Try it here : http://codepen.io/gabssnake/pen/KyJxp

Answer (score 1):

```html
<a onclick=ViewPdf(test.pdf) href="">


function ViewPdf(FileName) {
    var url = '../Home/GetPDF?fileName=' + FileName;
    window.open(url, '_blank');

}
```

Now write ActionResult like below

```
public ActionResult GetPDF(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] fileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Functions.GetConfigValue("CDXFilePath") + fileName);
                string resultFileName = String.Format("{0}.pdf", fileName);
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + resultFileName);
                return File(fileData, "application/pdf");
            }
            catch
            {
                return File(Server.MapPath("/Content/") + "FileNotFound.html", "text/html");
            }
        }
```